# How to fallback to entirely different index page if user has javascript disable?

Tags: php, javascript, fallback

I have a large, dynamically generated, single page website that heavily relies on javascript. I want to have a fallback for people without javascript.

Each version must have different php code, so basically I need an entirely different index page. I dont want to wrap EVERYTHING in javascript, and EVERYTHING ELSE in  tags. Unless there is an easy way of doing that.

What is the best way to load one page or the other depending on whether javascript is enabled or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, to directly answer your question, you could redirect the user away from the first index page if JavaScript is enabled using `location.href`. That is, if the user does not have JavaScript enabled, they will remain on page one. Else they will be redirected to the JavaScript version.

But the way I would generally go about doing this is to first make sure the website works without JavaScript; then add in the extra code for JavaScript after that plain version works.

```
<a href="foo.php" onclick="return foo();">Foo</a>
```

Here, if JS is not enabled, they will go to `foo.php`. Else, you can have the function `foo` do something and return false, thus keeping them on the page. The same thing can be done for forms.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `noscript` tag to provide the user with a way to the non-javascript page..

example: code at http://jsfiddle.net/xdYNE/ running (when JS off) at http://jsfiddle.net/xdYNE/show/

(***hint***: see it with JS disabled to understand..)

Answer (score -1):

Seems like putting a PHP redirect inside noscript tags would be the simplest way.

Comment: `<noscript>` is client side; you cannot put any PHP code inside them... You could do something like `<noscript><a href="...">Click here for non-JS version</a></noscript>`, but doing it the other way around is more transparent.

Comment: Didn't quite think that one through. Thanks!

Comment: @Matthew I beg to differ. I recently found this thread when viewing [**this question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006843/alternatively-load-page-via-php-if-ajax-fails) and have suggested to use `<noscript><?php echo "Sorry, you need to enable Javascript to submit this form."; ?></noscript>` will work (tested). Just thought you'd like to know that, because it did work for me.

Comment: @Fred, I simply meant that the PHP code will always run regardless if JS is available or not. In your example of an `echo`, there are no bad side effects. But doing a PHP redirect per this answer will not work because it will always get executed.

Comment: @Matthew I agree with you there Matthew. One has to wonder why options as such were never implemented inside; there must be a real good reason not to.